# Python- extracting data from one running code to another

Tags: python

I hope do describe my question accurate as possible:

I have 2 remote Rpi machines running 2 different python codes. Machine of type A is controlling its GPIO pins and monitor its status using python code A. Machine of type B is monitoring several Type A's using python code B.

My question is regrading code B : how can it get data of a running code ?

Comment: You will probably need some form of network communication between the two RPi, using something like builtin [`socket`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) or a library like [`pyzmq`](https://pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: @Delgan i'm hoping there is a more simple way ... :)

Comment: But the data are in different physical machines. How do you expect to share them, if not using a `socket` or some type of message passing system?

Comment: @JohanL can you please refer for a similar design?

Comment: Not really. But any distributed system will have to handle this particular issue.